# How can I export content-type and content from one site to another?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I got handed over a drupal 7 site with two branches, one is now in production and other is dev. I am working on dev and had to create new content types and made changes existing content types.

In the meantime other users made some changes to content-type and content. Administration want to merge content types and retain the latest content.
What is the workflow to do this kind of stuff.
In the past I only had to clone whole site so I used rsync to sync file and export/import db.

This looks like way more complicated than I anticipated as both sites have same content types but with some degree of variation in field names and types.

From my current Drupal knowledge it seems like a very complex task.

Where should I start and which approach/technique should I use?

I went through other answers and found that the [Node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module can export the node but how can I export the content and map the fields from one content type to another ?

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know your Drupal version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Node Export

Looks like you are already familiar with the [Node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module, allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation.

## Bundle copy

The [Bundle copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module has support for export/import of:

- Node types.
- Taxonomy.
- User.
- Field API fields.
- Field groups.